# Default File Display is Using Incorrect Image Style

Tags: 7, files

I'm using [Media-7.x-2.0-beta1](https://www.drupal.org/project/media). When adding an image with the default file display (default file display is identical to Original), it uses the "Medium" thumbnail display. I've checked to make sure the default is not configured to this display.

Where would these settings be saved that I could double check to make sure they were actually changed when I altered them? Is there any other reason for the Default display to be displaying the image in the wrong image style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some search, I got your issue and from where you can set that. So I delete my previous answer and following is the updated one.

As in my setting, I have four Image settings,

- Default
- Teaser
- Preview
- Wysiwig

Now, by default it is taking some `height` and `width`.

Now those all four setting you can change at `Admin/Structure/File types/Images/Manage file Display` and you can find all four image file set on right hand top corner in following images. Now, you can see as I have selected Default and at bottom of the page it is showing `None(original image)`.

> [image]

Note: Now, image uploaded in the body field area before save/post of the body content may not show what you have selected, but if you post it it will show what you image style you had selected. As stated in following image.

> [image]

Comment: To clarify, this isn't a content type specific issue. This is a File Type specific issue, i.e. happens with all files of File Type Image. This problem is taking place in the body field with a WYSIWYG.

Comment: Could you let me know, how did you set that setting for the file Type, So I can try at my end.

Comment: I did understand your issue, by mistake I downloaded beta2 as I downloaded using Drush, which by default download the latest one. Now as I check in my site, It uploads with different size in body field before posting area, but when you save/post that body, it changes it accordingly. But I am not getting from this size are coming, like in my case -Default, Teaser, Preview, Wysiwig. Will update you If i will get. But after posting the content It gets change Accordingly, No issue. Original gets original size.

Comment: I have updated my answer, Please have a look.

Comment: So I actually have those settings configured for the Default File Display for the Image File Type (i.e. Default File Display is set to Image Style of none). When I plug it in with Default display it still shows the Medium Image Style. This is why I'm so confused, haha.

Comment: One quick question..How do you determine that the posted image is medium size?

Comment: Good question. The dimension to which it is immutably set when it is displayed is identical to the dimensions of the Medium Image Display Style.

Comment: Can you check uploading different one different image with totally different dimension that medium, and check whether it is showing same as medium. In my opinion, till this stage, if you set everything properly, there is no way it should show always medium **UNLESS** the `img { width:_____; height:______;}`in your CSS file has the same dimension as  that your medium, then whatever you upload will all convert to medium dimension.

Comment: Here's what I did:
1. Add new File (grp.jpg) with dimension of 3264x2448 to see what happens when its really big.
2. In a WYSIWYG, open the Media Browser, choose the image I just added from library. 
3. Choose Display as Default and Save (this display, Default, has no enabled displays, like Original).
4. When I look at the URL of the image, instead of the path of the full image (/sites/default/files/grp.jpg), it links to the Medium style image (/sites/default/files/styles/medium/public/grp.jpg?itok=-ornBuPL).
The fourth is the confusing part. Why is it linking to that odd incorrect path?

Comment: Ultimately the URL bit is the problem. Why is it choosing to display the image at the medium file location, instead of the original image? This is actually how I can tell it's linking to the medium style, I should have said that before. (By the way thanks for all your help so far!!)

Comment: Ohhh....You do not have to choose from library.....Just add from desktop(save image on desktop, a fresh image download from internet). Then see, I will explain further, If you get it correct, waiting.

Comment: I have updated the answer with explanation.

Comment: That kind of makes sense, but when I select an image from the Library and select Display as 'Original,' it gives me the plain image (with the URL of /sites/default/files) with no dimension modifications. Shouldn't Default be able to do the same thing if it's configured to display in the exact same way as the Original file display settings?

Comment: I have some logical explanation for this, but let me test something on that, I will update you in few moments..

Comment: I have one question, How do you add the image file to your website folder And where, which you plan to use.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean, so I hope I'm answering the right question, but I add a given file by opening the Media Browser from the WYSIWYG (Media Browser v7.x-2.0-beta1), then selecting the file I want to upload from the upload tab, then selecting next, save, and submit with the "Display as" set to default. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes, you answered my question. Like some file on your desktop, then you will take that file using the Upload option of Media.  So this image file goes in system. And then this process add the file to Editor and you post that AND simultaniously this file will be added to library, so next time you wan to use, you can select from library.

Comment: Now, I checked again, and I did check your logic of 'default', and your logic is right. and I did check how media is selecting a file from library and I did came to know that, it always choose the original file size. Hence, what logic I explain in my updated answer is wrong. I will edit my answer. But I checked on my site every possibility, the Media module working as it should work. Just last thing I wan to point out, did you check you check your CSS element `img { }`.

Comment: OK. Yeah, I checked the CSS using the inspector in multiple browsers and there is no CSS influencing the sizing of it. I actually also followed both URLs (the one in the medium directory which it returns when I select default and the one to the original image) and when viewing just the image in the browser, that's how big it is. I even removed all the dimensional settings (both width and height) that were applying and none of that corrected the image. I'm going to start looking to see if the setting to display got hard-coded into the module somehow, as unlikely as that would be.

Comment: Given that this answer _should_ work, I'm marking it as correct. There must be some hidden misconfiguration which is unique to my site. However, others should know this is normally the method to address this situation.